# st_geomfromtext assertion failed using spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, geospark

When I rum the following code

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.sql("select -7.07378166 as longitude, 33.826661 as latitude");
    df.withColumn("ST_Geomfromtext ",
            expr("ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')'),4326)"))
            .show(true);
```

I get the following error :

```
20/07/22 14:39:56 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
 java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_GeomFromText.eval(Constructors.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown 
Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown 
Source)
```

I need your help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code the function [ST_GeomFromText](https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/geosparksql/expressions/Constructors.scala#L148) expects only 1 expression, but you have 2 - `concat(..)` and `4326`

Check examples [here](https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/api/sql/GeoSparkSQL-Function/)

Comment: Thank you for your help , I resolve it by doing that : df.withColumn("ST_Geomfromtext ",
                            expr("ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,'),4326'))"));

Comment: Please have you any idea about that , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038764/st-within-using-spark-java