# ST_WITHIN using Spark / Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, geospark

I have the following dataframe :

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
|longitude    |latitude         |geom              |
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
|-7.07378166  |33.826661        [00 00 00 00 01 0..|
|-7.5952683   |33.544191        [00 00 00 00 01 0..|                  
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

I'm using the following code :

```
Dataset<Row> result_f = sparkSession.sql("select * from data_f where  ST_WITHIN(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude_f,' ',latitude_f,')',4326)),geom)");
result_f.show();
```

But I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayData
at org.apache.spark.sql.geosparksql.expressions.ST_Within.eval(Predicates.scala:105)
```

**EDIT**

```
longitude : Double type
latitude  : Double type
geom      : Binary type
```

Any idea ? I need your help

Thank you

Comment: https://datasystemslab.github.io/GeoSpark/api/sql/GeoSparkSQL-Predicate/#st_within

Answer (score 2):

I don't think ST_GeomFromText is availble as constructing a geometry from text however there are:

- ST_GeomFromWKT
- ST_GeomFromWKB
- ST_GeomFromGeoJSON
- ST_Point
- ST_PointFromText
- ST_PolygonFromText
- ST_LineStringFromText
- ST_PolygonFromEnvelope
- ST_Circle

I suggest to use either `ST_Point` or `ST_PointFromText` and after that the predicate `ST_WITHIN`

Something like this:

```
Dataset<Row> result_f = sparkSession.sql("select * from data_f where  ST_WITHIN(ST_Point(CAST(data_f.latitude AS Decimal(24,20)), CAST(data_f.longitude AS Decimal(24,20))),geom)");
result_f.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but I get always the same error

Comment: please print the schema of your dataframe

Comment: Please check the EDIT Post